# Is it possible to use buttons as a link as well as pass a variable value in PHP?

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to create a button that is a link which also passes variable information, but I see that it is not being passed in the url, so it i snot working. Here are the attempts I have made:

```
<form><input type="button" value="link 1" onClick="myaccount.php?userinfo=0'"></form>

<FORM METHOD='LINK' ACTION='myaccount.php?userinfo=0'>
        <INPUT TYPE='submit' VALUE='Details'>
        </FORM>
```

If anyone can show me where i am going wrong that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needs to add `location.href`

```
 onClick="location.href = 'myaccount.php?userinfo=0'">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    <FORM METHOD='GET' ACTION='myaccount.php'>
            <input type=hidden name=userinfo value=0>
            <INPUT TYPE='submit' VALUE='Submit'>
            </FORM>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `method="link"` only `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` and some others. The `action` attribute of a form specifies where to send the data, while the `method` specifies how to do so. `GET`, for example, will append the variables and their values to the URL.

I'm guessing something like this would work:

```
<form action="myaccount.php?userinfo=0" method="get">
   <button type="submit" name="link" value="1">Details</button>
<form>
```

Comment: You guess wrongly. the `userinfo=0` querystring will be overwritten and only `link=1` will appear on the sent querystring. Had a POST been used, `link=1` would have been sent in the POST message body, and `userinfo=0` would appear on the sent querystring.